# What does System mean in Java code?

Tags: java

In Java code, what exactly is `System` as in `System.out.print` or `System.exit`? What is it for?

Comment: Read the docs: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html

Comment: Would like to Upvote Rob for his edit.

Answer (score 4):

`System` is just a class and `out` is just a static field into that class. Look here for more info: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html

Comment: System is not just a class, it's a `final` class.

Answer (score 3):

See javadoc:

- [System](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)

---

> The System class contains several useful class fields and methods. It
>   cannot be instantiated.
>
> Among the facilities provided by the System class are standard input,
>   standard output, and error output streams; access to externally
>   defined properties and environment variables; a means of loading files
>   and libraries; and a utility method for quickly copying a portion of
>   an array.

In short, it's a utility class with numerous static utility methods. It cannot be subclassed (due to its `final` modifier). And it cannot be instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

`System` is a class in the `java.lang` package, which is automatically imported. This is why you don't have to import these classes (the same for `String`, `Integer`, `Float`, etc...).

The class `System` has three static fields:

1. `out`, which is an instance of the `PrintStream` class, which is used for default ouput (stdout).
2. `err`, which is an instance of the `PrintStream` class, which is used for error output (stderr).
3. `in`, which is an instance of the `InputStream` class, which is used to read from the console (stdin).

Answer (score 0):

System is a `final class` which contains several useful class fields and methods. out is a field in System class, which is of type PrintStream and its the The "standard" output stream. and println() is the method defined in PrintStream class.

Answer (score 0):

System - it's a class.
System.out - an object field of this class.
System.out.print and System.exit - it's methods.

Comment: `out` is a static field in `System`.